# How to customize the generated rowmappers in jOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, vert.x, jooq

I have [a project](https://github.com/redhat-appdev-practice/vertx-openapi-jooq-multimodule/tree/Issue-7-_-Debug_createTodo_operation) using [jOOQ code generation](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/) in one of the [modules](https://github.com/redhat-appdev-practice/vertx-openapi-jooq-multimodule/blob/Issue-7-_-Debug_createTodo_operation/modules/data-access/pom.xml#L177).

That module is using a [Converter](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/#NA4B77) to map from `OffsetDateTime` to `Instant` and vice-versa. The problem I am having is that while this seems to work for the generated Table/Pojo/Record definitions, it is not working in the generated `RowMappers` class. The generated `RowMappers` code looks like:

```java
public static Function<Row,com.redhat.runtimes.data.access.tables.pojos.Todos> getTodosMapper() {
  return row -> {
    com.redhat.runtimes.data.access.tables.pojos.Todos pojo = new com.redhat.runtimes.data.access.tables.pojos.Todos();
    pojo.setId(row.getUUID("ID"));
    pojo.setTitle(row.getString("TITLE"));
    pojo.setDescription(row.getString("DESCRIPTION"));
    pojo.setCreated(row.getInstant("CREATED"));
    pojo.setDueDate(row.getInstant("DUE_DATE"));
    pojo.setComplete(row.getBoolean("COMPLETE"));
    pojo.setAuthor(row.getString("AUTHOR"));
    return pojo;
  };
}
```

But on the `Row` object, there is no method `getInstant`. Ideally, it should be calling `DateTimeConverter.from(row.getOffsetDateTime("<field>"))` using my Converter class. Is there a way to customize this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Something else I just noticed in the Maven output:

```
[INFO] 'com.redhat.runtimes.data.access.converters.UUIDConverter' to map 'java.util.UUID' could not be accessed from code generator.
[INFO] 'com.redhat.runtimes.data.access.converters.UUIDConverter' to map 'java.util.UUID' could not be accessed from code generator.
[INFO] 'com.redhat.runtimes.data.access.converters.DateTimeConverter' to map 'java.time.Instant' could not be accessed from code generator.
[INFO] 'com.redhat.runtimes.data.access.converters.DateTimeConverter' to map 'java.time.Instant' could not be accessed from code generator.
```

Perhaps that is why the RowMappers are not working?

**EDIT AGAIN**

I fixed the error above by including the converters dependency in the plugin dependencies but I am still getting an error compiling the `RowMappers` class.

**EDIT PART 3**

@lukas-eder - The RowMappers/DAOs are getting generated by the jooq-vertx library I guess. I will have to reach out to Jan Klingsporn and ask his advice.

Comment: What are these `RowMappers` (Spring?) and who's generating them (jOOQ isn't)?